# MaterialUI v5 breakpoints

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to understand how I can use the 'down' word in order to apply certain style for sm size and smaller using Material UI v5.

Currently this is what I have:

```
<Grid sx={{ flexDirection: { xs: 'column-reverse' }, }}>
 <Grid item xs={12} sm={7}>
  <Posts />
 </Grid>
 <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
  <Form />
 </Grid>
</Grid>
```

What I have noticed is that sx={{ flexDirection: { sm: 'column-reverse' }, }} applies to the breakpoint sm and up: https://mui.com/system/getting-started/usage/#responsive-values

Is there a way to make something similar so this style is responsive to the breakpoint sm and **down**?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve it by using the following:

```
sx={theme => ({[theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: { flexDirection: 'column-reverse' }})}
```